# Solving a determinant equation. Solve for $x$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Solve for $x$ where
$$
        \det\left(\begin{bmatrix}
        x & -1  \\
        3 & 1-x  \\
        \end{bmatrix}\right)
=\det\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&-3 \\
2&x&-6 \\
1&3&x-5 \\
\end{bmatrix}\right)
$$

My book doesn't explain this type of problem. Please be descriptive.

Comment: I think there is a typo, e.g. the left matrix sits in a different ring to the right matrix, they literally can't be equal

Comment: Two matricies with different dimensions cannot be equal. Your question is wrong

Comment: If it's meant to be that the determinants are equal, then it could be done.

Comment: page number? also edit question to have this information?

Comment: yes it is determinants here is the problem in chap 2 supplementary exercises pg. 221#16 http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/undergrad/ughandbook/content/ma106/elementary_linear_algebra_10th_edition.pdf

Comment: You would notice that the book wrote it as $\begin{array}{|cc|}x&-1\\3&1-x\end{array}=\dots$, the fact that the borders of the matrix did not have corners implies that we are taking the determinant.  You however wrote the matrices *with* corners, hence everyone's confusion.  You should make it clear next time that we are dealing with determinants by saying so, like I have edited the problem above.

Comment: In all fairness, I doubt OP had the $\LaTeX$ stills, but do keep it in mind for the next question @SarahS

Comment: Even without the skills to type well and use nothing but the best choices for notation, OP should be aware of the differences in the meaning of the notation and understand why people were so confused and avoid using misleading notation.  That is as bad as trying to use the symbols $|x|$ to denote the floor of $x$ just because you can't find how to type $\lfloor x\rfloor$... everyone will assume $|x|$ is denoting the absolute value instead of the floor unless they are told otherwise.  Without knowing how to type the symbols, using words would be preferred.

Comment: I wrote the problem the way the book wrote it so I'm sorry if there is an issue. Upon further inspection my print copy of the book is different from the online version so I was not following the online version either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So to solve this question, we need to calculate the determinant of both sides, so we have

$$
\det\left(\begin{bmatrix}
        x & -1  \\
        3 & 1-x  \\
        \end{bmatrix}\right)
=
\det\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -3 \\
2 & x & -6 \\
1 & 3 & x-5 \\
\end{bmatrix}\right)
$$

> For those you wanting to know how to do this in $\LaTeX$, it's

```
\det for functions like \tan, \sin, \det ...
\left(, \right) to have it match the size
\begin{bmatrix} 
entries separated by &'s (to indicate end of entry)
and \\'s to indicate a new row
and then an \end{bmatrix}
```

Now, the left hand side is $(x)(1-x) + 3 = -x^2 + x + 3$.

Recall that we can compute determinants by expanding across rows and columns, with $-1$'s where appropriate and the determinant of the minors.

The right hand side is (expanding from top row)

$$
1\times \det\left(
\begin{bmatrix}x & -6 \\3 & x-5\end{bmatrix}\right) - 0 \times \det\left(
\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 \\3 & x-5\end{bmatrix}\right) + (-3) \times \det\left(
\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 \\x & 3\end{bmatrix}\right)$$

From here we can do as above,
\begin{align}
&= 1 \times ((x)(x-5) +18) + (-3) \times (6 - x)\\
&= x^2 - 5x + 18 - 18 + 3x\\
&= x^2 -2x
\end{align}
So looks to me as if you have a quadratic to solve, I'll let you take the rest.

Comment: to the person who downvoted me, i'd love to know why, just comment with what i did wrong

Comment: SWelcome to the club of victims of mysterious downvotes ! $\to +1$ for your good answer.